# Training data for leg_detector?

Tags: ros, leg-detector, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the outputs from the leg_detector package, I'm wondering if it could benefit from a more diverse set of training examples. Notably, the detection confidence falls quickly as people  move away from the laser and it is fooled easily by round objects like chair legs.

Does anyone know if the original training data is available anywhere? Maybe also the labelling/annotation method that was used?

Relevant links:

- [here's](http://code.google.com/p/wu-robotics/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fpeople2)  an unofficial repo of leg_detector/leg_detector2.
- [this](https://github.com/DLu/people) is David Lu's fork of leg_detector
- [this](http://wiki.ros.org/srs_leg_detector) is the SRS leg_detector fork

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120271/training-data-for-leg_detector?/) by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 438 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The training data is not available. The people_experimental repo (which I can't find at the moment) is where the code originally came from. My code (the first two links you posted) were a fork of that.

Caroline Pantofaru was the maintainer there, but when I talked to her, she said that the training data was no longer available.

I do have a [collection of bags](https://code.google.com/p/wu-robotics/source/browse/#svn%2Fdata%2Fpedestrian_data) that I cobbled together that I intended to validate and test the leg detector with, but I did not follow up on that project.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on 2014-01-22**:
Yes, thanks! Do you know anything else about it? It looks like the features used are similar to those in People2D ([http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~spinello/people2D.html](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Espinello/people2D.html)), eh? Do you know if there's any high-level description of the tracker/detection matcher used?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-01-22**:
Caroline I believe said that this paper (http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4209616&tag=1) was the basis for the leg detector.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-01-22**:
Note: some of the hacks in the code are my own, and an improved version would be greatly appreciated by the community. Or at least myself and other HRI/ROS researchers.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-10-13**:
@David Lu Not sure if this is what you mentioned but I see a copied [people_experimental](https://github.com/mikeferguson/people_experimental/tree/master/leg_detector/config) repo.

**Comment by [ashish](https://answers.ros.org/users/23237/ashish/) on 2016-10-17**:
@David Lu I couldn't find the bags-collection at the above mentioned site. Is it because of SVN hosting issue on google-code?